# working with the php://stdin I/O streams

Tags: php

I know the way to open and read the content of the file with the `fopen` function like this:

```
@fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
```

But with the `php://stdin` i got bit confused

```
$in = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
```

Where should i specify the name of `txt` file that i attempt to read?

Comment: It's standard input; THAT is the stream, not a file.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand what standard input is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`php://stdin`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) is for CLI usage. You do not specify a filename directly in PHP then. It is typically utilized from the terminal like this:

```
echo "input text" | php script.php
```

or

```
cat textinput.txt | php do-something.php
```

Where the thing you *pipe* into the interpreter is what you receive when reading from stdin.

Btw, you can also just use the `STDIN` constant, without manually calling `fopen` first.

Comment: What should i do if i want to read a `txt` file then, please, i want an example showing the use of that.

Comment: For reading a file, see my second example. You do not specify the file in your PHP script, but leave that to users and the shell. That's the whole point of STDIN, to allow for input from unknown sources. -- I guess Wikipedia for once explains the concept better than I ever could: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams