# How to do so in Linux, so that when reading from a file, the current application receives data from another application?

Tags: linux, cryptography

Let's say I have a file "hello.txt" containing the text "Hello, world!"
I have application "textreader", that reads the file hello.txt and puts it in stdout.
Next, i have encrypted the file "hello.txt".  Can decrypt it a special library that can read the file byte by byte.

Ho do i can use application "textreader" to read from encrypted file as a normal file, using my library (or my application)? I can't write some temporary files under the terms of the problem.

It is possible to use named pipes (mkfifo), but prerequisite is the support seeking. File must be read randomly.

Does anyone have any ideas how i can to do it, if i haven't source code of "textreader"?

Answer (score 1):

Write a shared library that replaces the standard Linux I/O routines, and [load it with LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick).

This will work provided the application is dynamically linked to the C library - if "textreader" makes system calls directly, then interception won't work.

See also:

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795
- http://lca2009.linux.org.au/slides/172.pdf

Comment: I also thought about it. It is not the most elegant solution, but apparently no other.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using stdin?

If the textreader application converts `hello.txt` to stdout, simply pipe the output of textreader to your own application/script. For example:

`$ ./textreader | ./myapp`

Depending on what language you'll decide to use in your application, you can handle stdin the same way you'd handle most streams.

The following SO answers should give you more information as to how to read from stdin in different languages:

- Python: [How do you read from stdin in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450398/1242637)
- C++: [How to read until EOF from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202043/1242637)
- PHP: [working with the php://stdin I/O streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773602/1242637)

Wikipedia also [provides some helpful information regarding stdin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

**Edit:** Most streams are seekable, as you initially asked. I wrote a small example in C++ that shows how you can seek `stdin`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    int i = 0;
    std::string buffer;

    while (not std::cin.eof()) {
        std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
        if (buffer.find("while") != std::string::npos)
            if (i < 10)
                std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
            else
                std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::cout << "Line " << i++ << ": " << buffer << std::endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

You can compile the code by using `g++ test.cpp -o test` and then run it with `./test < test.cpp`. The code will output the beginning of the file twice, up to the beginning of the while loop. No buffering is done other than reading a single line from `stdin` at a time.

Comment: The method should support random seek.Reading from standard input can only be serial, as far as I understand.

Comment: @user1242996 I've edited my answer to add a simple seeking example in C++. Reading from stdin is no different than reading from most streams.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is done using filesystem filter driver which will perform decryption on-the-fly. In order to support random seek you would have to encrypt data in independent blocks (64-256Kb large) and cache those blocks in memory in decrypted form. Not a trivial task but can be accomplished. I am not aware of how to implement a filter driver on Linux (we offer a similar product for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

how about load the encrypted file in memory and decrypt from the memory buffer?
some script language such as perl, python, etc can read the whole file and assign it to a variable